# Stopping audio with OALSimpleAudio

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

If I loop a sound in XCODE using OALSimpleAudio on "touch down" and want to stop that audio on "touch up", how would the code look? I've tried "stopBg" method - but that stops all of my sounds, and I have multiple sounds running and I only want it to stop the "sample001".  Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

-(IBAction)sample001Touch {

```
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:sample001 loop:TRUE];
```

}

-(IBAction)sample001Release {

```
NSLog(@"Stop Please");
```

}

Comment: How is that question related to the IDE in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/interface_o_a_l_simple_audio.html

-(id < ALSoundSource > )playEffect:loop: returns id< ALSoundSource >, and according to http://kstenerud.github.com/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/documentation/protocol_a_l_sound_source-p.html
ALSoundSource has stop. Just save a reference and then you can stop it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<ALSoundSource> source;
```

--

```
- (IBAction)sample001Touch {
    self.source = [[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:sample001 loop:YES];
}

-(IBAction)sample001Release {
    [self.source stop];
    self.source = nil;
}
```